# brew install neovim failed

Tags: homebrew, neovim

Why the below error occurred when I wanted to install **neovim** via a **homebrew**?

```
==> Installing dependencies for neovim: libuv, luajit-openresty, luv, msgpack and tree-sitter
==> Installing neovim dependency: libuv
==> Pouring libuv-1.43.0.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/bytedance/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/e6dab71479a311084c88f44f8dbe535d87ad677c27a85144266f8d0168bce483--libuv-1.43.0.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
```

[image]

```
homebrew version:
Homebrew 3.3.9
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 62b6b918f65; last commit 2022-01-06)
```

Comment: Try a `brew update && brew doctor`; does that show anything noticeable?

Comment: it notice some warnings, but the problem was solved after i tried again.

Comment: FWIW, I was getting the same issue with `brew install --HEAD jq`, it would error at `==> Pouring automake--1.16.5.arm64_ventura.bottle.tar.gz
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/james/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/cbd9fb298ac58ddd98b7d9b90bf3c2957d0feca6f850d40c33fe3ce714ec5ada--automake--1.16.5.arm64_ventura.bottle.tar.gz`. I just ran `brew install automake` separately to get it working.